# Dimension of the intersection of two subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space with  $\dim(V)=6$. If $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $\dim(U)=\dim(W)=4$, find all possible values for $\dim(U\cap W)$.

My approach:

I used that $dim(U)+dim(W)- dim(U\cap W)\leq dim(U+W)$ and knowing that $dim(U+W)\leq dim(V)$ then:

\begin{align*}
   4+4-dim(U\cap W)\leq 6 \\
   8-6\leq dim(U\cap W)\leq dim(U) \text{  (or $\leq dim(V)$)} \\
   2\leq dim(U\cap W) \leq 4
 \end{align*}

How to justify (geometrically) that indeed the possible dimensions are $2,3$ and $4$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean geometrically? You can just define, say, $U$ and $V$ as certain subspaces of $V=\Bbb R^6$ with the required dimension of $U\cap V$. For example, $U$ is spanned by $v_1=(1,0,0,0,0,0)$, etc.

Comment: Use `${\rm dim}(V)$` or `$\operatorname{dim}(V)$` for ${\rm dim}(V)$.

Comment: Thanks for the observations, what I meant by geometrically  was exactly what you said.

Comment: @Shaun how did you write that code in grey rectangle?

Comment: Put the text between two `s, @Believer.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you. Just a query. `$\dim(V)$` will be easy no?

Comment: You're welcome! I didn't know `$\dim(V)$` works for $\dim(V)$, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_k=(0,..,1,..0)$, where the k-th position is $1$ and all other places are $0$.

For $dim(U\cap W)=4$, for example: $U=W=span\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$

For $dim(U\cap W)=3$, for example: $U=span\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}, W=span\{e_2,e_3, e_4, e_5\}$

For $dim(U\cap W)=2$, for example: $U=span\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}, W=span\{e_3,e_4, e_5, e_6\}$